# Upgrade sqlite3 to custom package

Tags: sqlite, rpm, centos7, yum, sqlite-json1

I have a server running centos7 with sqlite3 installed using Yum/rpm. By default the sqlite package is not compiled with the extension JSON1 which I need. The extension can be enabled when the package is compiled using the flag `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1` After working at it for a full day I've managed to find the RPM source files, updated the spec so it compiles with the flag, and recompiled it into a new package. Now I can run `rpm -U current-sqlite-package.rpm custom-sqlite-package.rpm` and upgrade to my custom package. Both yum and rpm say that the package but when I run `/user/bin/sqlite3 --version` it is still the old version.

How do I upgrade to my custom package? 
How does yum/rpm packages tie to the software in /user/bin?

Comment: What's the output from `rpm -qa |grep sqlite*`

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep sqlite` outputs `sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7.centos+json1.x86_64` which is my new custom package. `yum list sqlite` outputs `sqlite.x86_64 3.7.17-8.el7.centos+json1 installed` confirming that the new package has been installed.

Comment: If it is important `rpm -qa | grep sqlite*` with the asterisk produces no output.

Comment: New attempt. I've downloaded the C source code directly and recompiled with the flag: 

`wget "https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-autoconf-3170000.tar.gz";`
`tar zxvf "sqlite-autoconf-3170000.tar.gz";`
`cd "sqlite-autoconf-3170000";`
`CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1' ./configure;`
`sudo make install;` 

Now I have a working version of sqlite3 at `usr/local/bin/sqlite3` but I still don't know how to point the system at it instead of the old software in `/usr/bin/sqlite3`

Comment: if it won't break anything you could remove all the versions you have installed and start over. `yum erase <package name>` if that won't remove it do `rpm -e <package name>` then do `yum clean all` and reinstall from the rpm. It sounds like you have bits left over from other attempts and non standard builds...

Comment: Unfortunately I have other packages like cPanel that rely on the package so I can only replace it, not remove it. I've reinstalled the original package and ran `yum clean all` to return the system to where it was.

Comment: I took at look at my PATH and found that executing `sqlite3` is actually running the new version of sqlite. However, runing queries in a php script still attempts to use the old version.

Comment: ahh then try a httpd restart and see if it picks up the new/correct path

Comment: No luck, after restart php still points to old version of sqlite3. If I run `/usr/local/bin/php --ri pdo_sqlite` I get the following: 
`pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.8.10.2` which confuses me more as I don't know where or how the such an old library version has been installed (yum has sqlite v3.17 installed and the version I recompiled and installed in `usr/local/bin` is v3.17)

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of SQLite3 support runtime extension loading. So you can just download and compile the JSON1 extension as a separate .so file and load it via `.load ~/path/to/json1.so`

This will allow you to receive updates for SQLite via the default package manager and no need to rebuild it yourself.